ClickOnce Apps Automatically Disable Signing For Debug Builds
I am using VS2022.  I am using a DigiCert certificate to Sign the ClickOnce Manifests.  When I build for a release, I have to type in a PIN.  I'd like to avoid that when debugging.  Right now, I have to manually uncheck Sign the ClickOnce Manifests when debugging and then remember to recheck it prior to Publishing.
I found this old thread that suggested I could add a conditional to the vbproj to automatically not sign debug builds, but automatically sign release builds.  This didn't seem to do exactly what I'm looking for.  Here's the old thread: How can I disable code signing for debug builds in Visual Studio 2013?
Here's what I put into the vbproj:
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <!--  -->
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <!--  -->
    <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
</PropertyGroup>

I have also tried this:
From:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>

To:
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">
    <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>```

This didn't sign it in the publish phase :(
Any ideas what else I need to do to the vbproj?

You can add a condition to the properties related to signing to only apply when not in debug configuration.
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>...</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
    <ManifestKeyFile>...</ManifestKeyFile>
    <ManifestKeyPassword>...</ManifestKeyPassword>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>

